# Flutter Firestore get the Total number of document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I have `Withdrawals` stored in Firestore but every document has a collection of documents. I want to get all documents and every document collection.

**Firestore Database Structure:**
[image]

I tried many ways but didn't work for me. I also attached a photo of my database

**my Code:**

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('withdrawals').get().then((value) {
      print(value.docs.length);
    });
```

I have 2 Document on my withdrawal collection but it returns 0.

When I try to get a specific document collection it's working and returning data perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `node.js` it needs `=>` like the example below:

```
db.collection('withdrawals').get().then((value) => {
      console.log(value.docs.length);
});
```

try this in flutter:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('withdrawals').get().then((value) => {
      print(value.docs.length);
});
```

Comment: Let me know if this is working on your end

Comment: Thank you but I solved this issue. I also have a youtube channel.https://youtu.be/HC8YGWD-930

Comment: Great! You can post the solution as an answer to your question. So, you can help others with the same issue.